# SEO Domain Name Optimization

Tags: seo, domains

Quick question:

I'm trying to decide on the best domain name for my niche. I have it narrowed down to the following options:

keyword.co

mykeyword.com

keywordnetwork.com

Which of these domain names will perform the best from an SEO perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an SEO perspective:

keyword.co - perfect for the keyword but if you're targeting a specific country the .co (Columbia) TLD will hurt you. If not you're good to go.

mykeyword.com - Good keyword usage but not targeted toward any country

keywordnetwork.com - Good keyword usage but not targeted toward any country. If there is such a things as keyword density in domain names/URLs then technically you have diluted it a bit by having "network" in it but in practice this won't make much of a difference at all.

Remmeber, there's more to a domain name then SEO. If you don't keep your users in mnd you've lost before you've even begun. .coms are easy to remember vs country specific TLDs. Also, it wouldn't surprise me if people accidentally added the "m" to .co when typing in the first one. I'm not saying it's going to happen a lot but I can see it happening simply out of habit.

Comment: Just as an FYI, my target country is the US. I am still wary about the .co domain name. As I understand it, .co was recently purchased from Columbia to be marketed internationally as a supplement to .com. I'm just worried about its affect on SEO, but you say it shouldn't matter?

Comment: @James TLD only affect country specific search. In google.com searches all TLDs are equal.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise against getting a .co TLD unless you are targeting a service/product specifically for people/customers in Colombia.

Moreover:

1. As John Conde pointed out people could think that .com is the right one and that .co is an error so they might add the 'm' when looking for your url ending up in an not existing domain
2. I would rather be more confident to buy something (and in general more confident) from a .com domain than a .co domain from Colombia.